# A mixed mode Flutter Bottom Navigation bar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am wanting to include a Bottom Navigation Bar in my application that will be displayed on some pages but not other.
As I understand the the Flutter BottomNavigationBar widget re-renders the Scaffold Body property and does not actually route to another page and always shows the navigation bar. Would anyone have some advice on how I can have a bottom navigation that would look like the following where Tab 1 and Tab 3 route to a screen showing the navigation bar and Tab 2 and Tab 3 are screens that don't show the navigation bar?

[Bottom Navigation Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0IIH.png)

Comment: I have same issue then I try one thing I use one scaffold in every screen and I pass index in argument and when user click on bottomnav item I navigate as usual It means you have to use one common screen in your app or you can try key I don't know how to use it but it can work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to show the bottomNavBar in tab 1and 3 while hiding it in 2 and 4 right? I presume you have a variable that keeps track of the selected index lets call it `int _selectedIndex = 0`. In the bottomNavigation property you can show and not show it like below

```
bottomNavigationBar: _selectedIndex.isEven ? null: BottomNavigationBar()
```

Here it checks the _selectedIndex value (0,1,2,3 in this case) and if that is odd you show the page and the navigations (Tab 1 & 3) while if it is even (Tab 2 & 4) then you supply a `null` thus not showing the navigation. The only concern becomes how to navigate outside the two tabs without navigation but this should solve your immediate problem